# Comparing #include and using namespace std in C++ with import in Python

Tags: c++, python

I read through many pages on the internet about the `#include` statement and `using namespace std` phrase in C++ and I need some clarification. Since I already know Python I will use it as an analogy. First of all, in C++

```
#include library
```

and in Python

```
import library
```

are the same. Then, in C++

```
#include library
using namespace std;
```

and in Python

```
from library import *
```

are the same.

For example, if we compare the first analogy, we know that in C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

is similar to the code below in Python (similar in using std and #include):

```
import math

def main():
    print math.sqrt(12)
```

If we were to compare the second analogy, we have that in C++

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

and in Python

```
from math import *
def main():
    print sqrt(12)
```

are similar.

Can you correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: `#include` and `import` are quite different, as are namespaces in Python and `namespace`s in C++. Knowing both Python and C++, I can tell you that the two are sufficiently different that an analogy with Python isn't a good way of approaching these C++ concepts.

Comment: `using namespace std` is considered bad form and should be avoided.

Comment: `using namespace std;` can be considered very poor form in C++, as can `from X import *` in python. But the meaning of each is quite different. I think your analogy causes more confusion than is worth.

Comment: Is it possible if you guys can provide an analogy with perhaps java to help understand this concept, if python is a bad example?

Comment: I don't think an analogy with Java would be useful either. Basically, C++ does not have a concept of module. An `include` statement is a pre-processor directive, essentially a pre-compilation copy-and-paste. You still need to link in the corresponding compiled libraries, if any, into your executable.

Comment: A better analog than `#include library` would be `#include header`. Include directives have no inherent connection to libraries; they in effect copy text from the header, and that text need not relate to any library.

Comment: I wonder why people claim "using namespace std" is bad form when the alternative is typing std:: everywhere. Is not repeating yourself needlessly also bad form

Comment: @Brandin Being explicit is usually the opposite of bad form. My answer gives one reason for why it should be discouraged, though.

Comment: @leewangzhong I suppose if you want to use names like "max" its fine. But personally I don't wish to use names that are already defined by the stl. It would be like naming a function "printf" or something. Legal but dumb.

Comment: @Brandin Thing is, you would then have to know every single name you're dumping into the space. And you'd have to be careful of names that will be added to the standard library (not STL), or other libraries you use, in the future. And any file that includes your file also gets `using namespace std;`'d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#include` is "copy-paste this file". For example, you can `#include` a file into itself, and get [this ridiculousness](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/zsmall.hint). You can also have a snippet of code in a file and `#include` it everywhere you want.

Don't do this:

```
//forloop.txt
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    ARRAY[i] = VALUE;
}

//prime.txt
2147483647

//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main(){
    int prime = 
        #include "prime.txt"
    ;

    int arr[10];

    #define ARRAY arr
    #define SIZE 10
    #define VALUE prime
    #include "forloop.txt"
    #undef VALUE
    #undef SIZE
    #undef ARRAY

    for(int i=10;i-- > 0;){
        cout<<arr[i]<<'\n';
    }
}
```

The `using` directive is not strictly needed. C++ has an idea of "namespaces" that prevents, for example, your `max` function to be considered different from the `math` function in `cmath`. It looks something like this:

```
namespace std{
    int max(int i, int j){
        if (i<j)
            return j;
        return i;
    }

    //some variable declaration and initialization
    ostream cout(MAKE_BUFFER(stdout)); //std::ostream, if used outside
}
int max = 5;

int main(){
    std::cout<<std::max(3,::max)<<'\n'; //::max refers to global name "max"
}
```

`using namespace std;` practically means "If you can't find a name globally, try sticking `std::` in front and see if that's a name." People say it's bad practice to say `using namespace std` partly because if you `#include "F.h"`, and `F.h` has `using namespace std`, then your code also uses namespace std (due to copy-paste `#include`).

---

Python is not a compiled language. When you say `import X`, you're giving a command to the interpreter to do something (run some code and make some name). `#include` is more like telling the compiler what to do to continue compiling at this point.

`import` in Python kind of means, "attach the names in this module". So `import blah as x` means, "Every variable (including functions) in `blah` can be accessed as `x.THING`". It also calls the module's initialization stuff, which makes sense, because the variables need to be initialized before you can use them.

---

Java is also a compiled language. In Java, the `import` statement doesn't play with files, it plays with classes. Every piece of code in Java has to belong to a class.

But unlike the other two languages, `import` is not strictly necessary. `import` is actually closer to C++'s `using`. `import` simply adds names for classes you can already use, except only to the current class.

Here's some code using imports.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example{
    public static void main(String blargs[]){
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in your name and press Enter: ");
        System.out.println("Hello "+cin.next());
    }
}
```

Here's the same program, using no imports.

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(String blargs[]){
        java.util.Scanner cin = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type in your name and press Enter: ");
        System.out.println("Hello "+cin.next());
    }
}
```

Here's the same program, using all long names (`import java.lang.*;` is implicit in every Java source file).

```
public class Example{
    public static void main(java.lang.String blargs[]){
        java.util.Scanner cin = new java.util.Scanner(java.lang.System.in);
        java.lang.System.out.println("Type in your name and press Enter: ");
        java.lang.System.out.println("Hello "+cin.next());
    }
}
```

Here's the same program, using all the imports.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.util.System.out;
import static java.util.System.in;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String blargs[]){
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(in);
        out.println("Type in your name and press Enter: ");
        out.println("Hello "+cin.next());
    }
}
```