# include in C++ vs import in python

Tags: python, c++

is "import" in python equivalent to "include" in c++?

Can I consider namespaces from c++ the same way I do with python module names?

Comment: I'd say similar (not equivalent). That depends on how you consider python module names, but I'm not going to restrict your freedom of thought...

Comment: No. Look at [this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774877/comparing-include-and-using-namespace-std-in-c-with-import-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

`#include` in C and C++ is a textual include.  `import` in Python is **very** different -- no textual inclusion at all!

Rather, Python's `import` lets you access names exported by a self-contained, separately implemented **module**.  Some `#include`s in C or C++ may serve similar roles -- provide access to publicly accessible names from elsewhere -- but they could also be doing so many *other* very different things, you can't easily tell.

For example it's normal for a `.cc` source file to `#include` the corresponding `.h` header file to make sure it's implementing precisely what that header file makes available elsewhere -- there's no equivalent of that in Python (or Java or AFAIK most ohter modern languages).

`#include` could also be about making **macros** available... and Python very deliberately chooses to have no macros, so, no equivalence!-)

All in all, I think the analogy is likely to be more confusing than helpful.