# What is the difference between a module and a header file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python, and was doing some reading and came upon modules. If I understand correctly, they appear to function similarly to header files in c++ (like main.hpp which then can be included in the main file with `#include main.hpp`).

Are these functionally the same, or what is the difference between the two?

EDIT: to clarify, I mean user-defined modules, not numpy, re, rand, and others

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336318/include-in-c-vs-import-in-python) answers your question.

Comment: Python doesn’t split files into headers and implementations. So, no, they’re not equivalent at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant libraries and modules For example: 'import csv') which is usually found in the beginning of your Python code. You can include them in the program with the "import " just like header files in C++. So the difference is Libraries are a collection of modules written in C or Python and a module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.